# Can we connect two projects to the same SQL Server Express database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am facing a very weird situation where by my company wants me to use SQL Server Express. But the issue is I need to use the same SQL Server Express database for connection by different projects.

How do I do that?

I am using Entity Framework and C#.

Comment: and what is the problem? sql express supports multiple connections

Comment: just point your projects at it, same as you would sql server ???

Comment: How can i access the same sql express db from the second project?

Comment: @vini, just like you did in the first project. It doesn't matter.

Comment: If i create an mdf file inside one of my projects (App_Data folder) its not accessible from the other project

Comment: Don't keep the MDF in the App_Data folder.  "attach" it to your sql express server.  Then your 2 projects can connect to it as if it was a db on a regular sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to copy your `.mdf` from your `App_Data` folder into SQL Server Express's data folder, attach the database to your Express instance, and then change your connection string to reference the instance instead of the location of the `.mdf`.

[This answer to a similar question gives detailed, step-by-step instructions for this process.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959603/643591)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to attach local database file with `AttachDbFilename=` option in the connection string. But you can't simultaneously attach the same `.mdf` on a local drive with several concurrent applications (like you can do with MS Access).

Rather just install SQL Server Express on a central computer and open it up for remote TCIP/IP access, attach your database to it and change the connection string to an IP / instance one.